# Ciruclant Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the proof that a circulant matrix is normal? I've been trying to find some sort of pattern in $A^*A$ but as of yet I haven't been able to come up with a formula for why $A^*A = AA^*$.

Comment: Really?  Just write down the sum for $(A^*A)_{ij}$ and compare it to $(AA^*)_{ij}$.  Certainly there are nicer proofs (you can observe that the first row of $AB$ is a convolution of the first row of $A$ and the first row of $B$), but I don't see what's stopping you from finding any proof for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do better than that. For *any* two circulant matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB = BA$. And $A^*$ is circulant if $A$ is, so the result you wish to prove is a special case.

To prove $AB = BA$, note that [all circulant matrices have the same set of eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues) and are diagonalizable, so that any two (or more) circulant matrices can be [simultaneously diagonalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization/). That is, there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $UAU^* = D_A$ and $UBU^* = D_B$ are the (respective) diagonal matrices of eigenvalues. Then
\begin{equation*}
AB = (U^*D_AU)(U^*D_BU) = U^*D_AD_BU = U^*D_BD_AU = (U^*D_BU)(U^*D_AU) = BA.
\end{equation*}

(More generally, any set of diagonalizable matrices commutes if and only if the matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable).